# Disable Unity search "partners" across all present and future user accounts

Tags: scopes

We would like to disable the Unity default Amazon and other partners search.  I know this is easy to do for one account either through gsettings in terminal or under privacy in system settings.  But is there a way to do it once and for all, so that no user accounts presently available, or user accounts in the future, have this setting enabled?